# Приставка при- в приревновать

Tags: лексика, морфология, семантика, приставка

Что именно означает приставка при- в слове приревновать? В Розентале для этого случая у при- есть, как мне кажется, максимум два смысла, которые подходят к этому слову:

1. неполнота действия;
2. доведение действия до конца, результата.

Словари (например, Ожегов, Ефремова, Викисловарь) определяют "приревновать" тождественным "ревновать", то есть при- тут имеет второй смысл – результативность действия. Однако интуитивно я ее не чувствую, как, например, в словах "приехать", "примирить", "признать" и т.д. Наоборот, здесь больше подходит неполнота действия, его слабость. Как вам кажется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого глагола (с приставкой) характерна связка с известным предметом ревности посредством предлога *к*.

> Ну как ты меня могла приревновать к Анне?
>
> Надеюсь, что Вы расстались дружески, не успев поссориться и
> приревновать друг к другу.
>
> Представляешь, вздумал приревновать меня к Максу...
>
> Военфельдшер Лозовский, имевший повод приревновать какую-то женщину к
> лейтенанту Павлу Чульпенёву.

В случае «ревновать» это лицо предполагается, оно неконкретно или намеренно не называться.

> Яна может ревновать его всерьез и только прикрывать это остроумными
> шутками.
>
> Другим обманутым женам заботы ничуть не мешают ревновать, закатывать
> истерики и скандалы.
>
> «Наверно, матери просто нравилось ревновать», ― подумал вдруг он.
>
> Зачем мне читать про ревность или грусть в девятнадцатом веке, когда я
> и сама могу и грустить, и ревновать?..

Comment: Ревновать кого-то, приревновать(кого-то) к кому-то.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе "ревновать к" - 386 примеров, "приревновать к" - 36 примеров.

Comment: В 73 примерах обнаружил только два десятка «чистых». Больше ревнуют к абстакции: современности, руке, Бетховену, картине, чувству, словам, пустому. Показатеьный пример встретил: «Ревновать к денежной шкатулке? ― Ну, а он вас не приревнует к старому Шадурскому!»

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от контекста, некоторые глаголы с приставкой при- могут принимать оба упомянутых значения и (1) - неполноты действия, и (2) – доведения действия до конца, результата.
… приписать несколько слов к своему тексту (1) или приписать себе авторство (2).
… придавить платок, что бы не унесло ветерком (1) или придавить обломками рухнувшего здания (2)
Значение глагола «приревновать» (сов.) -  отреагировать (в той или иной форме) на испытываемое чувство ревности. Но испытывать чувство Р. это значит ощущать: беспокойство, недоверие, подозрение, опасение,  нервозность,  панику,  обиду, досаду, нетерпимость, отчаяние, злость, ненависть, гнев, ярость…
Как видим, (даже неполная) палитра переживаний очень широка, поэтому значение П. сильно зависит от контекста.
Например, можно «приревновать» совсем чуть – чуть, слегка, или старательно скрывать от  окружающих чувство Р. так, что бы о его наличии можно было только догадываться.
― С этого и началось… Приревновала. Вера Ивановна девушка умнейшая… и виду не подала, а ходить перестала. [П. Д. Боборыкин. Проездом (1884)]
Говорят, будто из ревности ― почем знать, может быть, даже к вам приревновала. [В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Ч. 5 (1867)]
Приятельницы ломали головы, и наконец открыли дело: Анна Степановна приревновала Marie к директрисе. [С. Д. Хвощинская. Воспоминания институтской жизни // «Русский вестник», NoNo 9-10, 1861]
― Признайся, приревновала, ― с угрюмой усмешкой упрекнул он. [Ольга Новикова. Мне страшно, или Третий роман // «Звезда», 2003]
Еще противнее стало. Он понял, что я приревновала его. ― Ну вот, начинается, ― серьезно и разочарованно протянул он. [Лидия Иванова. Искренне ваша грешница (2000)]

Изредка, П. связывают с ярким и откровенным проявлением чувства, когда вспышка Р. сопровождается крайней степенью раздражения и агрессивными действиями.
Бедусенко приревновал к кому-то свою жену и дело едва не дошло до драки. [В. А. Швец. Дневник (1968)]
Сегодня приревновал меня безо всякой причины и… выгнал из квартиры. [А. Т. Аверченко. Подходцев и двое других (1917)]
То приревнует она его и расцарапает ему лицо, то не сдержится он и форменно ее поколотит. [Н. П. Карабчевский. Речь в защиту Ольги Палем (1895)]
…Николай Алексеев Воробьев, услыхав от извозопромышленника Александра Егорова Власова о том, что последний, находясь на Кавказе, часто виделся с женой Воробьева, приревновал его к ней и произвел 4 выстрела из револьвера, убив Власова наповал. [Убийство (27.08.1910) // «Московские ведомости», 1910]

Палитру контекстных значений П. вряд ли удастся хоть как то размежевать по признакам (1) - «неполнота действия» или (2) - «доведение действия до конца, результата», но такие попытки были и будут еще. Так, вместо П. иногда используют слово «взревновать», у которого нет множественности значений «тянущихся» за приставкой при-, например:
Ты был нелеп. Ты взревновал меня к мужу. Это было с твоей стороны чрезвычайно пошло, потому что должен же ты был понимать, что я не могла же не быть женой своего мужа, с которым я только что обвенчалась; но… [Н. С. Лесков. На ножах (1870)]